# Should I add audio files on my mobile app locally or stream them from somewhere else?

Tags: cordova, mobile, meteor

I am currently writing a mobile app with Meteor and Cordova for a client. There is a section that contains a list of about 20 audio files. I checked them out and they are about 5mb each(maybe I could resize them somehow). Is this app going to be way too large? Should I upload them somewhere and stream the audio? What hosting services are suggested if I go this route?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to stream them online and offer an option to download them later if the user want-to , that will save you from having a heavy size of the app.
Buy a shared hosting service and upload them there , make sure that you choose an offer with a good bandwidth because that will consume it a lot ! ( well it depends on how many users and how many times the songs are played )